# Exclude a partial from certain views

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, iframe

in my current Rails app, I have a partial in my layouts folder for a navigation sidebar. I would like this sidebar to render for every page of my app except the `new` and `thankyou` actions of my score controller, because those two views are going to be a part of an iframe. To do this, I'm making another layout called `iframe.html.erb` where I'd like to put the logic to exclude the navigation sidebar.

Here is my application.html.erb layout file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>NPS</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="wrapper">

        <%= render 'shared/navigation' %>
        <%= yield %>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is my iframe.html.erb file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>NPS</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="wrapper">

        <%= if (current_page?(controller: 'scores', action: 'new') || current_page?(controller: 'scores', action: 'thankyou' )) do %>
            <%= yield %>
        <% end %>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I initially just had an `unless` statement in my application layout but that wouldn't work on the `sign-in` page because devise would be looking for those scores views in the devise folder. I'm also not very good with html.erb so I'm sorry if it's just a syntax thing.

Edit:

Here is the error I get with devise

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError at /users/sign_in
No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/scores"}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your application.html.erb...

```
<%= render 'shared/navigation' unless @disable_nav %>
```

Then in your score controller where you have you have your two views...

```
def new
  @disable_nav = true
  # ...
end

def thankyou
  @disable_nav = true
  # ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two layouts for that and your syntax is incorrect. Remove `iframe.html.erb`.

There are several ways to do it. Try this one in `application.html.erb`:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <% if !current_page?(controller: 'scores', action: 'new') && !current_page?(controller: 'scores', action: 'thankyou') %>
    <%= render 'shared/navigation' %>
  <% end %>

  <%= yield %>
</div>
```

It should just work. However, it can be improved. Move this logic into your `application_helper.rb`:

```
def should_show_navigation?
  !current_page?(controller: 'scores', action: 'new') && 
    !current_page?(controller: 'scores', action: 'thankyou')
end
```

And then, in your layout file (`application.html.erb`):

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <% if should_show_navigation? %>
    <%= render 'shared/navigation' %>
  <% end %>

  <%= yield %>
</div>
```

It gets more readable.

Comment: yeah I had something like this before, the problem is when I sign out, it gives me an error because of devise. I'll edit my post to show the error so you can understand better. because of that statement in the application.html.erb file, devise is thinking those controllers and views are in the devise subdirectory of my views

Comment: try using `current_page?(controller: '/scores', action: 'new')` then, see if this works.